# Create unique customerID everytime you create a new customer object. Is this possible? Java

Tags: java, class, methods, try-catch

So i have this idé that i can somehow generate a new customer ID everytime i apply a new
customer to my code. The thing is that I've created a class called `RandomNumbers`:

---

```java
public class RandomNumbers {

    public static SecureRandom secureRandom() {
        try {

            return SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");

        } catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e) { // NOSONAR
            return new SecureRandom();
        }
    }
}
```

---

I am now trying in my Customer class to somehow come up with a method that helps me put out a  new customerId everytime in my main method. Somehow I cannot figure it out. I've tried with boolean, to change it to string, integer. With if AND switch statments. You name it. Is this even possible?
Here is my Customer code ( Not done yet but yeah, im STUCK)

---

```java
public class Customer {

    private String name,
    email;
    String address,
    customerID;
    public String ShippingAdress;
    public String RandomNumbers;

    public void Customer(String name, String email, String address, String customerID) {

        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.address = address;
        this.customerID = customerID;
    }

    public String getCustomerId() {

        return customerID;

    }
    public String setCustomerID(String customerID) {

        return customerID;
    }

    public String getCustomerID() {

        customerId uniqeID = new customerID()
        SecureRandom uniqeID = new SecureRandom();

    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return ShippingAdress;
    }

    public void setShippingAdress(String address) {
        this.address = ShippingAdress;
    }

    public String getEmail(String email) {
        return email;
    }
}
```

---

I dont really know what more to say but it seems im not allowed to poste this if i dont
put in some more word so i tok the time and made an UML class diagram to to get an overlook but it seems i simply cannot wrap my mind around it so..
Had to remove some parts like my toString in the customer class if anyone wonders about that and aswell some brackets.

[image: UML class diagram]

Answer (score 0):

For what I understood You need to give an ID to every customer you create and that id will be uncheangable and unique for all customers.

```
public class Customer {

//Make it more readable

private String name;
private String email;
String address;
String customerID;
private String ShippingAdress;
private String RandomNumbers;

public void Customer(String name, String email, String address){

    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.address = address;

    //Initialize in the constructor the customerID with uuid (a unique id so you will not have duplication)
    this.customerID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
}

public String getCustomerId(){

 return customerID;

} 
public String setCustomerID(String customerID){

    return customerID; 
}

public String getCustomerID(){

    //customerId uniqeID = new customerID()//no
    //SecureRandom uniqeID = new SecureRandom();//no

    //You don't need to have a new id every time you retrieve your object information... it would not be an ID at all!

    //Just return the value
    return this.customerID;
}

   public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}
public String getAddress(){
    return ShippingAdress;
}

public void setShippingAdress(String address){
    this.address = ShippingAdress;
}

public String getEmail(String email){
    return email;
}
```